# Correlation failed at signin-oidc redirect

Tags: c#, oauth, correlation, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm running into the following issue when trying to authenticate an .NET Core 3.1 web application when hosted on a Virtual Machine behind an NGINX Load Balancer (Locally it works as expected and I only have one VM in the load balancer currently):

> Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location
>
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

I've done a lot of research and have tried a dozen fixes and none of them seem to work. Here is are snippets from my code:

Startup.Configure()

```
        // Initialize the ping options and get default values from the config
        var pingOptions = Configuration.GetSection("PingOAuthWebOptions").Get<PingOAuthWebOptions>();

        // Testing Stack OVerflow Example
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10000);
                options.Cookie.Name = "PINGSESSION";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = pingOptions.Authority;
                options.ClientId = pingOptions.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = pingOptions.ClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid"); // Added this
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
                    {
                        // Change from "HTTP" to "HTTPS" if requested and necessary
                        if (pingOptions.ForceSecureRedirect && ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.StartsWith("http:"))
                        {
                            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http:", "https:");
                        }

                        await Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    OnUserInformationReceived = ctx =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = ctx.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken;
                        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
                        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwt.Claims);

                        // Add app role
                        appIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Superuser"));

                        ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                };
            });
```

Startup.ConfigureServices()

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            var forwardedHeaderOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            };
            forwardedHeaderOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            forwardedHeaderOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeaderOptions);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

And finally, some of the things that I have tried:

> ```
> services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
> {
>     options.ForwardedHeaders =
>        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
>        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost |
>        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
>     options.ForwardLimit = 2;  //Limit number of proxy hops trusted
>     options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
>     options.KnownProxies.Clear();
> });
> ```

and

> app.UseHttpsRedirection();

and

> CookiePolicyOptions cookiePolicy = new CookiePolicyOptions()
> {
> Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
> };

and

> redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.State =
> options.StateDataFormat.Protect(redirectContext.Properties);

and

> app.Use((context, next) =>
> {
> context.Request.Scheme = "https";
> return next();
> });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:
After some testing with OP, it appeared  that auth cookies were blocked by NGINX because of size. Issue was resolved by changing NGINX config:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/605614

```
proxy_buffers         8 16k;  # Buffer pool = 8 buffers of 16k
proxy_buffer_size     16k;    # 16k of buffers from pool used for headers
```

---

Can you please check that you are able to run config below in dev? Before testing
instance behind NGINX, make sure you have registered that URL with your OpenId Connect provider.

Also check that X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto are passed on to your app. I've experienced problems with just that a few times after server changes.

I recommend testing this with a clean app as a proof-of-concept (POC). When POC is up and running in all enviroments, you can apply the changes to your existing code base.

In Startup.ConfigureServices

```
            var openIdConnectSettings = new OpenIdConnectSettings();
            Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(openIdConnectSettings);

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie()
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = openIdConnectSettings.Authority;
                    options.ClientId = openIdConnectSettings.ClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = openIdConnectSettings.ClientSecret;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
```

In Startup.Configure

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute( ...

            // required in order to get https for OpenIdConnect
            // must come before app.UseAuthentication();
            var forwardedHeaderOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            };
            forwardedHeaderOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
            forwardedHeaderOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeaderOptions);
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        ....
```

Config class

```
    public class OpenIdConnectSettings
    {
        public string Authority { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thank Roar for the prompt response.

I have validated that the URL is registered with the OpenId Connect Provider (I had issues with Http being used behind the load balancer and there being a mismatch error at one point. I put a fix for this into the Auth Library App. Not sure if this could be causing issues??)

I have cleaned up the code as much as i could and removed the reference to the library. Again, it's working locally but not when hosted behind NGINX.

Comment: Hi Troy. Things should work with SSL termination in LB (http between LB and your app). I don't think things will work when using http for OpenId Connect end-point in your app. I don't have an env to verify the latter, sorry for that.

Comment: So I'm not totally sure what you mean for the OpenId Connect end-point in my app:

Because our certs are located on the LB, I had to add the line for:
'ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.Replace("http:", "https:");'

are you saying that you don't think that will work? All other endpoints are using HTTPS.

Comment: I have also noticed the following in the event viewer:
Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
'.AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc.xxxxxxx'' cookie not found.

Comment: I'm refering to /signin-oicd end-point. If you specifiy this with http at your OpenId Connect provider and you have https redirect at LB, things will fail. BR

Comment: ... the error message you have, are you using `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` in your app? Try to remove that if you have it. When doing https redirect in LB, there is no need for it.

Comment: I am not using app.UseHttpsRedirection() - I did try it but found that it caused more errors. Looking at the headers in the network trace, The "General > Request URL" is HTTPS. The "response headers > host" does not specify a protocol (just website.com)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225952/discussion-between-roar-s-and-troy).